# getting a value of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Im learning JavaScript and Im having problems trying to get the value of HTML of textareaElement.   Theres lots online and because of all the information available its making it more confusing. I understand the idea behind the DOM, but not sure how to do the code. I am also trying to use add an event listener to store data in local storage, but without any luck.

```
// Add a text entry to the page
function addTextEntry(key, text, isNewEntry) {
  // Create a textarea element to edit the entry
  var textareaElement = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
  textareaElement.rows = 5;
  textareaElement.placeholder = "(new entry)";


  // Set the textarea's value to the given text (if any)
  textareaElement.value = text;

  // Add a section to the page containing the textarea
  addSection(key, textareaElement);

  // If this is a new entry (added by the user clicking a button)
  // move the focus to the textarea to encourage typing
  if (isNewEntry) {
    textareaElement.focus();

// Get HTML input values
var data = textareaElement.value;
```

}

```
// ...get the textarea element's current value
  var data = textareaElement.value;

  // ...make a text item using the value
  var item = makeItem("text", data);
  // ...store the item in local storage using key
  localStorage.setItem(key, item);
  // Connect the event listener to the textarea element:
  textareaElement.addEventListener('onblur', addTextEntry);

}
```

HTML is:

```
<section id="text" class="button">
    <button type="button">Add entry</button>
</section>
<section id="image" class="button">
    <button type="button">Add photo</button>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" />
</section>
```

[HTML][1]

Comment: The provided example lacks two closing curly braces, it's not clear, where exactly are you trying to read `var data = textareaElements.value;`. Is it inside the function or somewhere else in the code? An another thing is, that [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Technical_summary) can't contain HTML, its content is plain text only.

Comment: And where is `textareaElements` (plural) coming from?

Comment: Why can't you use jquery? Search documentation about it, you can use val(). Simple and fast.

Answer (score 2):

'textareaElements' is not plural as you have it here:

```
var data = textareaElements.value;
```

This is the correct form:

```
var data = textareaElement.value;
```